# Request for name of structure related to isomorphism

Tags: functions

You have two functions $f: A \rightarrow A,\quad g: B \rightarrow B$, which map onto their own domain, and a bijective function $t: A \rightarrow B$, which transforms back and forth between the domains of $f$ and $g$. They have the relation $\forall a\in A: t(f(a)) = g\big(t(a)\big)$.

Is there a name for this thing or for something more general, like when $f$ and $g$ are not required to map onto their own domains?
Else, can we transform this into something with a known name? This is something related to an *isomorphism*, <s>but an isomorphism requires a binary relation, not an unary operation/function $t$</s>.

Update 2022-05-30:
I think I was wrong when I said the above, which is now strike-through text. I think an isomorphism doesn't require a binary relation. Is this correct?

Then this thing is simply an isomorphism with an unary operation.

Comment: Its called an isomorphic canonical map with prestacks

Comment: It should be $t(f(a)) = g(t(a))$.

Comment: @WhatsUp thanks for the hint. my fault that the question got so little response.

Comment: I would say $f$ and $g$ are conjugates.

Comment: Interestingly, I almost forgot that I have asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536934/what-is-the-name-of-this-relationship-between-two-functions). The comment of @JairTaylor reminds me of that.

Comment: So telling from the comments and other sources, I presume we can say that t is an isomorphism between the two structures (A, f) and (B, g) and hence the functions f and g are conjugates.

Comment: You could also call $t$ a "change of variables".